# psgrep alias to show process id and command

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I want to rewrite this function so that it shows only the command name and the arguments without having to specify all those options to `awk`

```
function psgrep() 
    # show process id and command with arguments
    ps aux | grep "${1:-.}" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20}'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search for a specific executable (technically, for processed based on their name), some `ps` implementations such as that of HP/UX (where it comes from) or of `procps-ng` can do everything for you:

```
ps -o pid,args -C "$1"
```

If you want a more general search based on the process arg list (as your use of `ps u` suggests), you can post-process the output of `ps -A -o pid,args` for instance with `awk` to do extended regular expression matching:

```
ps -A -o pid,args | RE="$1" awk 'NR==1 || $0 ~ ENVIRON["RE"]'
```

(beware the regex is matched against the pid and argument list).

Here the regexp is passed to `awk` via the `RE` environment variable rather than `-v` as:

- it avoids having the regexp showing up in the `awk` process's own arg list, which could end up it being selected.
- it works around the mangling of backslashes (common in regular expressions) that `-v` otherwise does.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the actual `pgrep` tool, which has been around since 2007:

https://github.com/jvz/psgrep

Comment: Don't know about *psgrep* but *pgrep* is older than that. It comes from Solaris 7 (1998)

Answer (score 0):

Most systems have a `pgrep` command (initially from Solaris in the late 90s) to search for processes based on either their name (as reported by `ps`) or arg list (as reported by `ps -f` or your BSD-style `ps u`).

```
pgrep -lf extended-regular-expression
```

Would report the processes whose arg list (concatenation of the arguments with spaces) matches the extended regular expression.

In most implementations including the original one from Solaris, the ones on BSD and the toybox (Android) one, with `-l`, that returns the pid and what the regexp matches againt, here with `-f` the arg list, but with the implementation from procps-ng as found on most GNU/Linux distributions, you need `pgrep -af extended-regular-expression` instead.